# How to maintain selected checkbox on pagination Bootstrap Table

Tags: c#, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I using the component Bootstrap Table http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/.

Assuming I have populated the table with 20 records on the first page and I have three records that are checked, then when I change to the second page and then return to the first page, the records are no longer checked. There is some property that I can keep the states of objects when I am moving between pages?

There are something in https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/372 but I can't to do.

Comment: See: [Bootstrap Events Table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#events)

Answer (score 1):

Added an example: Maintain selected on server side:

https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#issues/917.html

Credits to: https://github.com/wenzhixin